# How to target the root directory in a website for a page published using cd_storage_conf?

Tags: 2013, content-delivery, configuration

I'm trying to target the directory location specifically after publishing a page.

If I have a page with a .xml extension and in my cd_storage_conf.xml. I've added this:

```
<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" defaultFilesystem="false">
    <Root Path="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.com" />
</Storage>

<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">
    <Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".xml" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile" />
</ItemTypes>
```

I'm expecting that the file would then be deployed to the root of the site but instead what I'm getting is:

- c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.com\us\en\page.xml

To me, there seems to be two issues here:

- The /us/en/ is a publication within Tridion. We have one for several other countries like /uk/en/ etc. This is causing a set of new directory to be created. Why?
- Why is the page.xml not added within the root of test.com?

Has anyone encountered these before?

Answer (score 2):

Check your Publication's `Publication Path` property in the Content Manager - Suspect you'll find that it is set to `\us\en`, which is dictating where your page in the root Structure Group is deployed.

To make your page publish without that extra path, you'd need to remove that property from the Publication but that would affect everything else when republished. You'd have to implement some publication specific storage nodes the `cd_storage_conf.xml` in order to restore the paths for the other item types.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for your comment. That path is necessary within Tridion to structure the site and determine how to navigate to other sites. Is there no way of getting around this without changing that? Is there no way to simply target a directory without creating any publication directories?

Comment: @TimAlonso was just updating my answer to include that info. You'd have to remove the publication path and then implement the equivalent in your storage config somehow. I don't think that's an easy work-around for you. Easier to find another option for your XML file in my opinion.

Comment: Hi David. I'll keep that in mind and I'll keep looking for other potential alternatives. Thanks.

Comment: If the XML file is something that isn't specific to a Publication, could you create a new Publication with no Publication Path specified and publish it from there?

Comment: I could but it seems excessive for a single XML file though.

Comment: Agreed. Still easier than changing all of that storage configuration though :)

Comment: @Tim. If it is just one XML file, can you not publish that from the parent publication rather than creating a child publication? Just create a group and enable publishing for that group and at the parent publication level, to make sure that Tridion security is still intact.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind items with their publication. The code below should give you the expected result.
Where **ID** is publication id of your site “test.com”

```
<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" 
                           Id=" filesystemDocRootPublicationId">
    <Root Path="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.com” />
</Storage>
<Publication Id="ID" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">
   <Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".Xml" 
         storageId=" filesystemDocRootPublicationId" />
</Publication>
```

Comment: <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id=" filesystemDocRootPublicationId">
        <Root Path="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.com” />
  </Storage>
<Publication Id="ID" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">
       <Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".Xml" storageId=" filesystemDocRootPublicationId" />
  </Publication>